# How to mute YouTube video and don't interrupt music playing with audio focus handling?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, android-audiomanager

I'm trying to use `android-youtube-player` library (https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player) to play YouTube videos, which I want to mute when no headphones are on or when user's music is playing. The problem is that even if I mute the video with `youTubePlayer.setVolume(0)` in `YouTubePlayer.onStateChange`, music stops when the video starts playing. If I continue playing the music, the video stops. The standard Google YouTube library can't solve this use-case at all.

I tried this code, but this doesn't help. Do you have any suggestions how this can be solved?

```
override fun onStateChange(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer, state: PlayerConstants.PlayerState) {
    if (state == PlayerConstants.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
            val audioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
            if (!Utility.isHeadsetConnected(context) || audioManager.isMusicActive) {
                audioManager.requestAudioFocus (object : AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {
                    override fun onAudioFocusChange(focusChange: Int) {
                        if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
                            audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this)
                        }
                    }
                }, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
                youTubePlayer.setVolume(0)
            }
        }
}
```